# I need help with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I have two tables - `employee` and `department`. 

1. `employee` table contains column id,employee name and dept_id
2. `department` table contains column id, department name.

I need exact department name which contains 

1. maximum employee and 
2. no employee
```

Edited:

```
Apologizing for bad grammar, here is the example for above two questions what i need.
1. for eg: if two department contains same number of employees, i need to show both department not single by limit.
2. for eg: if more than one department contains 0 employees, i must show those departments particularly.
```

Comment: @Harry Joy: Subject line says "I need help with a MySQL query."

Comment: He's using MySQL (notice the tag). That said, What do you mean by "maximum employee" and "no employee"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the first question:

```
WITH epcount(dept_id, ep_count) AS
(
    SELECT dept_id, COUNT(*) AS ep_count
        FROM employee
        GROUP BY dept_id
)
SELECT d.name FROM epcount AS ec1 JOIN department AS d ON ec1.dept_id=d.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM epcount AS ec2 WHERE ec1.ep_count < ec2.ep_count)
```

Answer to the second question:

```
SELECT name FROM department AS d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM  employee AS e WHERE d.id=e.dept_id)
```

Comment: I just noticed that the asker is looking for MySQL solution. My answer to the first query used some SQL Server syntax. Any way, except the WITH clause creating epcount temporary table, the idea about how to write such a query's WHERE clause is all the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
select department_name as `department name`, 
       count(*) as `number of employees`
from employee 
        inner join department 
            on employee.dept_id = department.id
group by department_name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

i think that should do it.  i've not done anything with mysql in a while.

edit: missed the second question

```
select department_name as `department name`, 
       count(*) as `number of employees`
from employee 
        left join department 
            on employee.dept_id = department.id
group by department_name
  HAVING count(*) = 0
```

Comment: Isn't it having count(*) = 0 instead of where? http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php

Comment: The first query is incorrect. It currently returns the first dept that contains the maximum number of employees. Not all the depts that contain that number. The second is incorrect too: the join ensures it'll return no rows.

Comment: @Denis, to the second point i will concede.  things done in haste, blah blah blah.  to the first, it is a matter of opinion. he asked for the department, singular, and that is how i wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a sorted list of departments, sorted by number of employees.

```
SELECT `dept`.`id`, `dept`.`name`, COUNT(`employee`.`id`) as `employee_count`
    FROM `dept` LEFT JOIN `employee`
        ON `employee`.`dept_id` = `dept`.`id`
    GROUP BY `dept`.`id`
    ORDER BY `employee_count`
```

To get departments with no employees, add:

```
AND `employee_count` = 0
```

...before the GROUP BY.

To get the department with the most employees, add `DESC LIMIT 1` to the end.

Comment: Desc limit 1 to the end is incorrect. It currently returns the first dept that contains the maximum number of employees. Not all the depts that contain that number. As is the employee_count clause, since the join makes it return no rows.

Comment: Edited to make it a LEFT JOIN. The question suggests that only one department contains the maximum number of rows (although that might just be the OP's poor grammar). I admit the imprecision here, and figure the OP can select based on his needs. Thanks for the correction, by the way! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question right, you need:

```
select department_name,
       count(employee.dept_id) as num_employees
from department
left join employee on employee.dept_id = department.id
group by department_name
having count(employee.dept_id) = 0 or
       count(employee.dept_id) = (select count(dept_id)
                   from employee
                   group by employee.id
                   order by count(dept_id) desc
                   limit 1)
```

Comment: i both like and don't like this answer.  it is exactly what the op asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Query that shows department names with maximum employees and number of employees in it:

```
SELECT department.name, COUNT(employee.name) from department
 INNER JOIN employee
 ON employee.dept_id = department.id
 GROUP BY department.name
 ORDER BY COUNT(employee.name) DESC limit 1
```

Query that shows departments with no employees:

```
SELECT department.name from department
 LEFT JOIN employee
 ON employee.dept_id = department.id
 HAVING COUNT(employee.name) = 0
 GROUP BY department.name
```

If you need to show it in one query, paste first query, add UNION ALL and then paste second query.

Comment: The first query is incorrect. It currently returns the first dept that contains the maximum number of employees. Not all the depts that contain that number.

Comment: @Denis - it turned out to be incorrect after OP edited his question. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0b5ed70b-ac3c-4318-9d7c-de39e54b52a4/view-source